# Updated ASP.NET Web API Tutorials on Microsoft Site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm so confused as to what version of the ASP.NET Web API I should be learning and where the best sources of information are. Many of the tutorials came out during the various stages of beta and alpha. From what I remember the latest framework varies a good amount from alpha and beta.

Are the tutorals on the MS site up to date? Some of them came out early Feb of 2012, are those worth looking at too or has the framework changed a lot since then?

(Referring to http://www.asp.net/web-api/videos)

Comment: The [ASP.Net Web API tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api) should be your best bet. It gives you *foundational* information/grasp of the API.

Comment: Thanks, but which tutorial are you referring to?

Comment: It's listed on the page, here's a [direct link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api). Go through it and the topics in the navigation side bars (right side).

Answer (score 1):

The tutorials on http://www.asp.net/web-api should have all been updated to work with the RTM release of ASP.NET Web API.